# To Get Trigger script source from VB6?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000

I want to get trigger script source from vb6. the database is using sql server2000.
i have trigger in a table. i just want to get trigger script at run time from vb6. this is possible? if yes please can anybody help me. advance in thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get all triggers on a table (or view) with something like this

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects
WHERE parent_obj = OBJECT_ID('MyTableName') AND xtype = 'TR'
```

Than you can get source T-SQL of any trigger (or any stored procedure) using this

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'MyTriggerName'
```

Comment: To get all the triggers, you should add an additional where clause criteria, "And xtype = 'TR'".  Otherwise you may get other object types (like primary keys).